# getting video thumbnails from vimeo

Tags: ios, vimeo

In my app i want to display the videos uploaded by a particular user in his Vimeo account.
I have completed the OAuth steps and got the video_id's of the video's uploaded by user. I tried to download the thumbnails for videos so that they can be displayed in table view or collection view.
Vimeo has provided the api method using that i got the response like this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.getThumbnailUrls&video_id=72961770"];
```

but i pasted the user id there. i tried another approach so that the user id is loaded dynamically.

```
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.getThumbnailUrls"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url consumer:consumer token:token realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];


    OARequestParameter *p0 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"video_id" value:[array objectAtIndex:0]];


    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObject:p0];
    [request setParameters:params];
```

but i got an error saying that Msg = Method not found.
can you help me to get the id dynamically or is there a way to give the video_id as a parameter to the url. Thank you

Comment: user id or video id you mean ? The first link should be fine, isn't it?

Comment: I mean the videos id's. In the first link i copied the video id from console and pasted it there. But when the app is running how can we paste it like that. we have to give the video_id through a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a string for url and paste until video_id=.

```
NSString *url = @"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.getThumbnailUrls&video_id=";
```

and after that use stringByAppendingString method to append the video_id value to it and use it.
This is also not a direct way but somehow enables you to get the video thumbnails dynamically without having to paste it

Comment: This link doesn't work for me. Don't know if it ever did but I pasted it into a browser (inserting video id) and got `Invalid consumer key`